# Applying texture to SVG and change components dynamically

Tags: javascript, node.js, svg

Have been trying to figure this for more than a week now,
Looking out to apply a texture to an SVG Image programatically and also change some components of it.Like Change type of collar on a shirt and change it's texture.
Tried out a PNG Image with shadow and changing the DIV Element Background but it does not give a good feel.
Read somewhere that can Achieve this using LWIP(Light Weight Image Processing) but most examples were to rotate the Image maximum or give a background color to it while rotating.

```
<div class="color" style=" background-image: url('gr6.JPG');">
<img src="spe.png">
</div>
```

some samples that I wish to achieve.

https://josephchanan.com/customize/#

https://www.bombayshirts.com/custom/shirt#

Answer (score 0):

Would be nice to see some code, but my suggestion would be to export svg with backgrounds using illustrator, copy the markup give your target elements Id's use Crome inspect to see what's what, access any svg Element by Id with Jquery, you can do it as long as SVG code is inline and not requested as an image like `'<img scr="my.svg"/>'` - wont work. then you can play and animate your SVG however you like

```
<svg>
<defs>
  <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="100">
    <image xlink:href="myTexture.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
  </pattern>
  <pattern id="img2" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="100">
    <image xlink:href="myTexture2.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
  </pattern>
</defs>
<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="url(#img1)" />
</svg>
<script>
$('svg circle').attr('fill','url(#img2)'); // just changed texture programmaticly

</script>
```